# Why my VS code appear white line and blurry?

Tags: visual-studio-code

my vs code keep appearing like this. This happen only in vs code, other application and software is normal
[image]

I already check for update and reinstall. I can't see what am I doing with this view

Comment: disable graphics acceleration

Comment: still didn't work

Comment: how did you do it? It has worked for all the others with the same question